# How to understand the Union of Zeir Anpin and Malchut in Assiya

Tags: tefilla, mysticism-kabbalah, chasidut-hasidism, chabad, practical-kabbalah

BH

I understand the world goes through a process of Seder hishtalshelut.

So how to understand the union of ZA and Malchut in the world of Assiya?

And how does this happen through the Tzimtzum?

Answer (score 2):

In terms of kabbalistic nomenclature, *Olam HaAsiyah*, meaning the *World of Action*, is referring to this material, physical world which we occupy.

The union of *Z"A* (meaning *Zeir Anpin d'Dachar*, the male reproductive organ) and *Malchut* (meaning *Nukvah*, the *feminine* or *female* in general and more specifically the *female reproductive organ*) is characterized  by the actual point of union of the two names, יהוה, which pertains to Dachar, and אהיה which pertains to Nukvah.

The union of the two to be one is the six letter name of G-d, אהיהוה (*gematria Lev* or *heart* לב which implies the innermost aspect of that name, which is alluded to in the first sentence of the Torah, with the word Bereshit בראשית, meaning *the six letter name created*, ברא שית. This follows the explanation in Sefer Raziel HaMalach, also known as Sefer Toldot Adam Kadmon.

The next two words of the first sentence ברא אלהים explain that from that initial state of oneness that contained the potential for all of Creation, there arose and was manifest actual reproduction and diversification by way of male and female and offspring. This also follows the teachings of Rabbi Moshe Chaim Luzzato in Sefer Adir b'Marom.

That the name Elohim arose from the six letter name via the transformation of *the striking of stones*, meaning (Aleph times Heh) א times ה, (Yud times Heh) י times ה, (Vav times Heh) ו times ה, together with the Kollel is 5 plus 50 plus 30 plus 1 equals 86 or Elohim אלהים.

That this name expands and evolves further to manifest אל״ה- -י״ם
as אהיה – יהוה which is 26 plus 21, together with the 2 names and Kollel which is 50 meaning י״ם.

That point of union, which in the six letter name was the innermost aspect of the name represented by  only the single Yud-Heh יה, (This י״ה is the concept of Nekudah, Kav, Shetach, *the form of the letters Yud and Heh*, ( the letter Heh ה whose form is derived from the *Miluy*, the letters of expansion, of the letter Yud, *Nukuda* itself (יו״ד becomes the letter ה Heh). נקודה, קו, שטח (In the language of Geometry, Point, Line and Area or Field. That *geometry*, the measure of the Earth from the Greek root *Geo*, like Geology and Geography, which is a contraction of Gaia, *Earth Mother*.) which is the basis of all existence according to the Torah. See Sha’ar HaYichud v’HaEmunah by Rabbi Hillel Paritcher.) is now manifest by two times Yud-Heh or י״ה-י״ה, which in reverse order of the At-Bash transformation is Tzimtzum צ״ם-צ״ם. While אל״ה expands via the transformation of *the striking of stones* to manifest the Good name אהוה which is gematria טוב and is also ה-  (Heh times Vav) meaning Lamed (ל)    - א  or א-הו-ה which pertains to offspring and is the Roshei Teivot of the conclusion of the first sentence, את-השמים ואת-הארץ.

So to summarize, in Asiyah, this is the union of husband and wife, to be fruitful and multiply, producing children.

Comment: @RabbiKaii Without getting too graphic, look around the world today at the distortion and perversion of the act of procreation, something truly holy, that has been and is separated from the kedusha. Every aspect of media & entertainment is immersed in it. This is the root behind the breakdown in relationships between men & women. (Think, for example, the Shidduch Crisis) The pathology is obvious and apparent. It manifests in all manner of emotional & psychological disorders. Pornography is one of the biggest businesses online & results in massive human suffering.

Comment: Exactly, I'm asking if the case of the question is referring to what you just said?

Comment: The question, and my answer, are emphasizing that proper connection and relationship. It is Kodesh and results in an increase and diversification of life. When action is taken to sever that connection (what I describe in my last comment), it results in the opposite. חי אני נאום יהוה.

Comment: @RabbiKaii To put it another way, the Action is the primary thing המעשה הוא העיקר, but Action without intention is like a body without a soul, meaning a dead corpse. תפילה בלי כוונה היא כגוף בלי נשמה היינו פגר מת. This is what we say each day at the beginning of morning blessings.

Comment: Thanks for that, these points are very close to my heart, and I seek your wisdom. I have seen for example in the Arizal's Likkutei Torah Noach, it mentions how the union in asiya is considered corrupt, and sounds to me like what you are describing, so any further reading to deepening my understanding to get closer to your level would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Zeir Anpin is the Parzuf which combines the Sefirot from Chesed to Yesod. The six of them.The giving, male energy. The six days of the week. The six millenia of from the creation of Adam.The Kudsha Brich Hu.

And Malchut is the seventh Sefira,  the recieving, female energy.The Shabbat, the messianic age.The Shechina.

So Yichud Zeir Anpin and Nukve in Asiya is Yichud Kudsha Brich Hu an Shchinte in this World. Means: an abundance of blessing throgh the unity of G-d blessing and our ability to recieve.